# converting decimal to exponent and mantissa

Tags: c

I am trying to convert a decimal number (329.39062) to binary (exponent, mentissa). I keep getting segmentation fault. on running the gdb test, It shows me feof. I have changed alot but it keeps showing me the segmentation fault at the same point. Where am i going wrong? Thank you for all the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* valueToConvert(int value);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        FILE* input;
        FILE* output;

        input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
        output = fopen(argv[2],"w");

    float value;
    unsigned char *charValue = (unsigned char *) &value;
    int exponentValue;
    long mantissaValue;

    while(!feof(input))
    {
        fread(&charValue, sizeof(float),1, input);
        exponentValue = ((charValue[0] & 0x7F) << 1)|((charValue[1] & 0x80) >> 7);  
        mantissaValue = ((charValue[1] & 0x7F) << 8)|((charValue[2] & 0xFF) <<8) | (charValue[3] & 0xFF);
        fprintf(output,"%d %s %s\n",(charValue[0] & 0x80 >> 7),valueToConvert(exponentValue - 127),valueToConvert(mantissaValue));
    }
}

char* valueToConvert(int value)
{
    int counter = 0;
    char* conversion = calloc(32,sizeof(int));
    while(value>0)
    {
        if((value%2 == 1) && (value%2 != 0))
        {
            conversion[31 - counter++] = '1';
        }
        if((value%2 == 0) && (value%2 != 1))
        {
            conversion[31 - counter++] = '0';
        }
        value = value/2;
    }
    return conversion;
}
```

Comment: [Which floating-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format)[point standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) [were you using?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple_precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: Shouldn't `fread(&charValue, sizeof(float),1, input);` be `fread(charValue, sizeof(float),1, input);`?

Comment: i think i am using IEEE 754

Comment: @Magtheridon96 i dont know how i missed that, thank you. That does solve the segmentation fault but i dont get the correct output.

Comment: "while(!feof(input))" is the wrong way to check for end of file in C.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy, but when using input file, i cant using EOF, since it returns an integer, where as feof gets the file pointer. What else could i use ? if not feof?

Comment: @Mani: Read until fread fails: while (fread(charValue, sizeof(float), 1, input) == 1) ...

Comment: also i have a question, i have not freed the memory i just noticed, does that , can it effect the output?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy, could you explain me a little bit about the difference? i read online just now i think i am a bit confused on that part. Also if i used fread, my output its 1 1, where as earlier it was 1 1 0. Though the output is wrong. Whats the difference? 
thank you for the help. I highly appreciate it.

Comment: @Mani: feof returns true not when the last item has been read from the file, but after the first _failed_ attempt to read. So a loop on !feof will make one iteration too many. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
fread(&charValue, sizeof(float),1, input);
```

That should be

```
fread(charValue, sizeof(float),1, input);
```

Because `charValue` is a pointer.

---

To address your problems with the output, you're filling the buffer backwards after initializing it completely with `0` via `calloc`, so `fprintf` is hitting `0` (a `char` used to signify the end of a string) and stopping "prematurely".

Here's a fast binary string function:

```
void fast_d2b(int x, char* c) {
    int i;
    for (i = 31; i >= 0; --i) {
        *(c++) = '0' + ((x >> i) & 0x1);
    }
}
```

It's based on the one shown [here](http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~gim/Papers/fast_d2b.pdf).
Only differences are that my variation doesn't write to the buffer backwards and it writes `'0'` and `'1'` instead of integral values `0` and `1`.

Comment: i agree, i am sorry i should have seen that, but i missed it. 
on running the file i get the output as 1 1 0 in 3 lines. why could that be?

Comment: That's because `calloc` is initializing the values of the `char*` you're allocating to `0`, simulating an end-of-string. Also, you're filling the `char*` backwards, leaving the initialized `0`s in the beginning causing `fprintf` to print the part of the `char*` that you _didn't_ manipulate.

Comment: so if i do a memory free towards the end, ( before the return statement) , will that help?

Comment: Thank you for the link, i have a question regarding your previous comment. i ddn get filling the char* backward statement, if you could tell me what you meant, will be of great help.

Comment: It means you're filling the `conversion` array starting from index `31` and approaching `0` because `counter` is initially `0`.

Comment: thank you for the explaining. I am still going wrong somewhere as i am not getting the correct output, could you please hint me towards that?

Comment: Could you added the updated version of the code in the question? (Link to a pastebin of it)

Comment: i have not changed my code much, except the '&' sign in fread.

Comment: You still need to use something like the fast_d2b function to get a binary string with bits starting from index 0 so you can validly print it.

Comment: I am sorry, i dont understand where i can put this code in my code. if you could help

Comment: All what the function does is take an `int` and a desired buffer (`char*`) and it converts that `int` to a binary string and stores it in that passed buffer. Yes, it will work for anything.